# Bash - How to do a normal counter?

Tags: bash, shell

So I'm used to do what I call (not sure if it's the official name) "counter", and basically do task that involve a certain range or number:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -x
get_total2=$(echo "$@")
while [ $get_total2 -gt 0 ]; do
    echo $get_total2
    get_total2=$(expr $get_total2 - 1)
done
```

Example using `echo`.

But as code suggest, it isn't a "normal" counter (as in, in normal order), but a reverse one...and I never knew how to do that, though I'm sure it's easy enough and I'm just overthinking it.

How could I make the above code work in a "normal" count instead of reverse order?

Comment: Why not use `get_total2=$((get_total2 - 1))`?  It's simpler.

Comment: Well, if simpler is the goal, in bash: `((get_total2--))` is simpler. :-) @unxnut

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop in bash to count up.  Consider, for example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -x

total="${1}"

for ((i = 0; i < total; ++i)); do
    echo "${i}"
done
```

If I run that, then I get:

```
$ ./ex.sh 3
0
1
2
$
```

The `for` loop is structured like:

```bsh
for ((init; condition; update))
```

- The `init` portion is run once before the loop starts, and is used to initialize the variable.
- The `condition` portion is evaluated each time through the loop.  When the condition becomes `false`, then the loop stops
- The `update` portion is evaluated after each pass through the loop.  `++i` is a short hand for `i = i + 1`

In this case, you get the following sequence of steps through the loop

- `i = 0`
- `0 < 3` -> true
- `echo 0`
- `++i` (`i = i + 1`) # i becomes 1
- `1 < 3` -> true
- `echo 1`
- `++i` (`i = i + 1`) # i becomes 2
- '2 < 3` -> true
- `echo 2`
- `++i` (`i = i + 1`) # i becomes 3
- `3 < 3` -> false # loop terminates

Comment: +1 for the cleaner implementation :) didn't thought of using `++i` either.

Answer (score 2):

Here are four alternatives, the first two are for bash, one down, one up.
The next two loops are valid in POSIX sh (which also work in bash),
again, one counting down and one counting up.

```
#!/bin/bash -

n=${1:-10}

       for ((i=n-1;i>=0;i--))        ; do    printf ' %s ' "$i"; done; echo
       for ((i=0;i<n;i++))           ; do    printf ' %s ' "$i"; done; echo

i=$n;  while [ "$((i-=1))" -ge "0"  ] ; do    printf ' %s ' "$i"; done; echo
i=-1;  while [ "$((i+=1))" -lt "$n" ] ; do    printf ' %s ' "$i"; done; echo
```

And the result of running the script will be:

```
 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0 
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

### Walkthrough

The first two loops use the for loop available in bash, ksh, zsh:

```
for (( start ; test ; execute )); do
```

- So, after setting the value of `n` to the value of the first argument (if it exists) and to 10 if it doesn't. Lets assume that n is set to 10.
- The for loop sets `i` (the counter) to one less than `$n` : `i=n-1` or 9.
- The test part is executed and `9` is `>=` than `0`.
- The printf gets executed with with an `i` of `9`, `9` gets printed.
- The final execute part of the loop gets executed and i is reduced `i--`.
- The loop tests again and `8` is `>=` than `0`.
- The printf gets executed, 8 gets printed.
- The `i--` gets executed, `i` becomes `7`.
- Repeat until we get`i` to become `0`.
- The test is still true, `0` is `>=` than `0` (equal in this case).
- The `0` gets printed.
- On the decrement `i--`, i becomes `-1` and:
- Now the test fails `-1` is **not** `>=` than `0`
- The loop is exited.
- A final `echo` is executed, moving down to the next line.

End result: 9 to 0 get printed on the same line: `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`

#### Loop 2

The second loop is what you ask for: an ascending loop. Very similar to the one above, but starts at 0 and ends at 9. Printing `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

#### Loop 3

- `n` gets set to 10 (could change is the script is given another parameter).
- `i` gets set to this value `i=$n`.
- While the test (`[...]`) that follows is true execute the printf.
- Inside the test, the first thing is to reduce `i` in `1` with `i-=1`. Which unrolls to `i = i - 1`. (`i--` is not available in `sh`). That is inside an arithmetic expansion `$((...))` and quoted (to avoid issues with IFS). That arithmetic expansion results in `9` (and `i` retains that value for the next loop).
- That value of `9` gets compared numerically `-ge` to find out if it is **G**reater or **E**qual to `"0"`.
- As `9` is `>=` than `"0"`, the printf gets executed, `9` gets printed.
- The loop repeats, now `i` is `9` and gets decremented in one to `8`.
- The `8` is still `>=` than `"0"` and 8 gets printed.
- Repeat until `i` has been decremented to `0`. As the test is still true: A value of `0` is still `>=` (equal in this case) to `"0"`. A `0` gets printed.
- The counter is reduced to `-1` which makes the test fail, and the loop gets exited.

#### Loop 4

Almost the same loop as above but counting up.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
get_total2=$(echo "$@")
count=0
while [ $count -lt $get_total2 ]; do

    echo $count
    
count=$(expr $count + 1)
done
```

You'd enter the number to stop counting at when prompted. I may have syntax errors though, didn't check. Also there might be simpler ways to do this.

Comment: You can replace the last count line with just `((count++))`

Comment: @annahri Agreed, I was trying to keep the code as close to OP's original code as possible though. The hope was it would increase their understanding of how to modify code.

Answer (score 1):

Your exact solution:

```
set 4
for ((get_total2=$@; get_total2 > 0; get_total2--))
do
    echo "$get_total2"
done
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Some other variations, using `((i++))` or `((++i))` directly while `echo`ing

---

Using square brackets :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

total="$1" i=0

echo -n "Using i++: "
while [ $i -lt $total ]; do echo -n " $((i++)) "; done; echo

i=0

echo -n "Using ++i: "
while [ $i -lt $total ]; do echo -n " $((++i)) "; done; echo
```

Output:

```bsh
$ ./count.sh 5
Using i++:  0  1  2  3  4 
Using ++i:  1  2  3  4  5
```

---

Using `c-style` :

```
total="$1"
while (( i < total )); do
  echo -n " $((i++)) " # or " $((++i)) "
done; echo

# total: 5
# output i++: 0 1 2 3 4 
# output ++i: 1 2 3 4 5
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `until` :

```
until (( i == total )); do echo -n " $((i++)) "; done; echo
# count.sh 5
# output: 0 1 2 3 4
```

---

**Some explanation:**

`echo $((i++))` will print first then increment while `echo $((++i))` will do the opposite.

So, if you have `x` with initial value of `0`, by doing `echo $((i++))` it will print `0` then `x` becomes `1`. Proof:

```
$ echo $((x++))
0
$ echo $x
1
$ echo $((++x))
2
$ echo $x
2
```